# Receiving attachment from gmail using imap

Tags: java, email, gmail, imap, jakarta-mail

I'm making a small app for accessing gmail and getting messages with attachments.

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.put("mail.user", login);
        props.put("mail.host", pop3Host);
        props.put("mail.debug", "false");
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        // set this session up to use SSL for IMAP connections
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.class", "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        // don't fallback to normal IMAP connections on failure.
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback", "false");
        // use the simap port for imap/ssl connections.
        props.setProperty("mail.imap.socketFactory.port", settings.getPop3Port().toString());
                props.setProperty("mail.imap.partialfetch", "false");
                props.setProperty("mail.imaps.partialfetch", "false");
        props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", settings.getSmtpAuth().toString());
        Session session=null;

        session = Session.getInstance(props, new GMailAuthenticator(login, password));

        Store store = null;
            store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect();

        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("Inbox");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
        Flags seen = new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN);
        FlagTerm unseenFlagTerm = new FlagTerm(seen, false);
        SearchTerm st = new AndTerm(new SubjectTerm(subjectSubstringToSearch), unseenFlagTerm);

            // Get some message references

            Message [] messages = inbox.search(st);

            System.out.println(messages.length + " -- Messages amount");

        //Message[] messages = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), false));
        ArrayList<String> attachments = new ArrayList<String>();

        LinkedList<MessageBean> listMessages = getPart(messages, attachments);
        for(String s :attachments) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
        inbox.setFlags(messages, new Flags(Flags.Flag.SEEN), true);

        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader (
            new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        for (int i=0, j=messages.length; i<j; i++) {
            messages[i].setFlag(Flags.Flag.SEEN, true);
        }
        inbox.close(true);
        store.close();
        return listMessages;
    }

    private static LinkedList<MessageBean> getPart(Message[] messages, ArrayList<String> attachments) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        LinkedList<MessageBean> listMessages = new LinkedList<MessageBean>();
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        for (Message inMessage : messages) {

            attachments.clear();
            if (inMessage.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                MessageBean message = new MessageBean(inMessage.getMessageNumber(), MimeUtility.decodeText(inMessage.getSubject()), inMessage.getFrom()[0].toString(), null, inMessage.getSentDate(), (String) inMessage.getContent(), false, null);
                listMessages.add(message);
                System.out.println("text/plain");
            } else if (inMessage.isMimeType("multipart/*")) {
                System.out.println("multipart");
                Multipart mp = (Multipart) inMessage.getContent();
                MessageBean message = null;
                System.out.println(mp.getCount());
                for (int i = 0; i < mp.getCount(); i++) {
                    Part part = mp.getBodyPart(i);
                    if ((part.getFileName() == null || part.getFileName() == "") && part.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
                        System.out.println(inMessage.getSentDate());
                        message = new MessageBean(inMessage.getMessageNumber(), inMessage.getSubject(), inMessage.getFrom()[0].toString(), null, inMessage.getSentDate(), (String) part.getContent(), false, null);
                    } else if (part.getFileName() != null || part.getFileName() != "") {
                        if ((part.getDisposition() != null) && (part.getDisposition().equals(Part.ATTACHMENT))) {
                            System.out.println(part.getFileName());
                            attachments.add(saveFile(MimeUtility.decodeText(part.getFileName()), part.getInputStream()));
                            if (message != null) {
                                message.setAttachments(attachments);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                listMessages.add(message);
            }
        }
        return listMessages;
    }
//method for saving attachment on local disk
  private static String saveFile(String filename, InputStream input) {
  String strDirectory = "D:\\temp\\attachments";  
  try{
  // Create one directory
  boolean success = (new File(strDirectory)).mkdir();
  if (success) {
  System.out.println("Directory: " 
   + strDirectory + " created");
  }
  } catch (Exception e) {//Catch exception if any
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
  }
        String path = strDirectory+"\\" + filename;
        try {
            byte[] attachment = new byte[input.available()];
            input.read(attachment);
            File file = new File(path);
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            out.write(attachment);
            input.close();
            out.close();
            return path;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return path;
    }
}
```

**MessageBean**:

```
 public class MessageBean implements Serializable {
    private String subject;
    private String from;
    private String to;
    private Date dateSent;
    private String content;
    private boolean isNew;
    private int msgId;
    private ArrayList<String> attachments;

    public MessageBean(int msgId, String subject, String from, String to, Date dateSent, String content, boolean isNew, ArrayList<String> attachments) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.dateSent = dateSent;
        this.content = content;
        this.isNew = isNew;
        this.msgId = msgId;
        this.attachments = attachments;
    }

    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }

    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }

    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }

    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }

    public Date getDateSent() {
        return dateSent;
    }

    public void setDateSent(Date dateSent) {
        this.dateSent = dateSent;
    }

    public String getContent() {
        return content;
    }

    public void setContent(String content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    public String getTo() {
        return to;
    }

    public void setTo(String to) {
        this.to = to;
    }

    public boolean isNew() {
        return isNew;
    }

    public void setNew(boolean aNew) {
        isNew = aNew;
    }

    public int getMsgId() {
        return msgId;
    }

    public void setMsgId(int msgId) {
        this.msgId = msgId;
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getAttachments() {
        return attachments;
    }

    public void setAttachments(ArrayList<String> attachments) {
        this.attachments = new ArrayList<String>(attachments);
    }
}
```

I can connect to my mail account and see amount of unseen messages, but it seems that `MessageBean` doesn't get populated with attachments.

The biggest problem is that i develop my app on a computer that doesn't have an Internet connection. So i build jar, go to computer that has inet, `java -jar` it and stare at NullPointer exception. I can't debug this crap. Could someone, please, spot where is my mistake.

**EDIT**
This code works for **gmail pop**, with another connection obviously.

Comment: Could you add the stack trace that is generated along the `NullPointerException`?

Comment: Its when i try to `messageBeans.getAttachments.get(0)`

Answer (score 0):

becuase your list is null when you get elements from it, so you can make new ArrayList object inside MessageBean, and then copy the elements

```
  private List<String> attachments= new ArrayList<String>();

  public MessageBean(int msgId, String subject, String from, String to, Date dateSent, String content, boolean isNew, ArrayList<String> attachments) {
        this.subject = subject;
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
        this.dateSent = dateSent;
        this.content = content;
        this.isNew = isNew;
        this.msgId = msgId;
        this.attachments.addAll(attachments);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The JavaMail FAQ has [debugging tips](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) as well as [tips for using Gmail](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#gmail).

What value are you using for pop3host?  Hopefully it's "imap.gmail.com" and not "pop.gmail.com".

Note that you can remove all those socket factory properties, you don't need them.

Answer (score 0):

```
    package com.thread.test;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.mail.Folder;
    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.Multipart;
    import javax.mail.Part;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Store;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;

    public class ReadMailThread implements Runnable{

    private Thread readMailThread;
    private String threadName;
    public ReadMailThread() {
    readMailThread = new Thread(this);
    readMailThread.start();
    }
    public ReadMailThread(String s) {
    threadName = s;
    System.out.println("creating thread :: "+threadName);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
    System.out.println("Thread Started "+threadName);
    String saveDirectory = "D:/Ganga/attachment";
    Properties props = new Properties();
            props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
            try {
                Session session = Session.getInstance(props, null);
                Store store = session.getStore();
                store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "******@gmail.com", "******");
                Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
                inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
               /* Message msg = inbox.getMessage(inbox.getMessageCount());
                System.out.println("Message Size is "+msg.getSize()/1024 +" KB");
                System.out.println("Message Size is "+msg.getSize()/1024*1024 +" MB");
                Address[] in = msg.getFrom();
                for (Address address : in) {
                    System.out.println("FROM:" + address.toString());
                }
                Multipart mp = (Multipart) msg.getContent();
                BodyPart bp = mp.getBodyPart(0);
                System.out.println("SENT DATE:" + msg.getSentDate());
                System.out.println("SUBJECT:" + msg.getSubject());
                System.out.println("CONTENT:" + bp.getContent());*/

                Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
                for (int i = 0; i < messages.length; i++) {

                String contentType = messages[i].getContentType();
                String messageContent = "";

                String attachFiles = "";
                if (contentType.contains("multipart")) {
                Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) messages[i].getContent();
                int numberOfParts = multiPart.getCount();
                for (int partCount = 0; partCount < numberOfParts; partCount++) {
                MimeBodyPart part = (MimeBodyPart) multiPart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                if (Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(part.getDisposition())) {
                String fileName = part.getFileName();
                attachFiles += fileName + ", ";
                part.saveFile(saveDirectory + File.separator + fileName);
                } else {
                messageContent = part.getContent().toString();
                }
                }
                if (attachFiles.length() > 1) {
                attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
                }
                } else if (contentType.contains("text/plain")
                || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
                Object content = messages[i].getContent();
                if (content != null) {
                messageContent = content.toString();
                }
                }

                  /*System.out.println(messages[i].getSize() + " bytes long.");
                  System.out.println(messages[i].getSize()/1024 + " KB long.");
                  System.out.println(messages[i].getSize()/1024*1024 + " MB long.");
                  System.out.println(messages[i].getLineCount() + " lines.");
                  String disposition = messages[i].getDisposition();
                  if (disposition == null){
                    //Do Nothing
                  }else if (disposition.equals(Part.INLINE)) {
                    System.out.println("This part should be displayed inline");
                  } else if (disposition.equals(Part.ATTACHMENT)) {
                    System.out.println("This part is an attachment");
                    String fileName = messages[i].getFileName();
                    System.out.println("The file name of this attachment is " + fileName);
                  }
                  String description = messages[i].getDescription();
                  if (description != null) {
                    System.out.println("The description of this message is " + description);
                  }*/
                }
                inbox.close(false);
            } catch (Exception mex) {
                mex.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    public void start(){
    if(readMailThread == null){
    readMailThread = new Thread(this, threadName);
    readMailThread.start();
    }
    }

    }

    package com.thread.test;

    public class MailTest {

    public MailTest() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Thread Name :"+Thread.currentThread().getName());
       ReadMailThread rmt1=new ReadMailThread("remoteThread1");
       ReadMailThread rmt2=new ReadMailThread("remoteThread2");
       ReadMailThread rmt3=new ReadMailThread("remoteThread3");
       ReadMailThread rmt4=new ReadMailThread("remoteThread4");
       ReadMailThread rmt5=new ReadMailThread("remoteThread5");
       ReadMailThread rmt6=new ReadMailThread("remoteThread6");
       ReadMailThread rmt7=new ReadMailThread("remoteThread7");
       ReadMailThread rmt8=new ReadMailThread("remoteThread8");
       ReadMailThread rmt9=new ReadMailThread("remoteThread9");
       ReadMailThread rmt10=new ReadMailThread("remoteThread10");

       rmt1.start();
       rmt2.start();
       rmt3.start();
       rmt4.start();
       rmt5.start();
       rmt6.start();
       rmt7.start();
       rmt8.start();
       rmt9.start();
       rmt10.start();

    }

    }

package com.equinix.gse.apps.me.tas.app.ec.process.snmp.fivemins;

import com.equinix.gse.apps.me.tas.app.ec.dao.snmp.Snmp5MinsDatabaseReadThread;
import com.equinix.gse.apps.me.tas.core.TasException;
import com.equinix.gse.apps.me.tas.core.util.TasConstants;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * User: vreddy
 */
@Service
public class Snmp5MinsCache {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Snmp5MinsCache.class);
    private static final String CLASS_NAME="Snmp5MinsCache";
    private static final String SNMP5MINSDATABASEREADTHREAD="snmp5MinsDatabaseReadThread";

    @Autowired
    private  ApplicationContext ac;

    public Map<String,Long> getCache() throws TasException{
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(TasConstants.THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
        int startCounter = 1;
        int endCounter = TasConstants.SNMP_EXDB_BATCH_SIZE;
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.append("select CUSTOMER_PORT_ID,IF_INDEX,SWITCH_NAME  from (" );
        query.append("select CUSTOMER_PORT_ID,IF_INDEX,SWITCH_NAME, ");
        query.append("row_number() over (order by CUSTOMER_PORT_ID )r from IXP_PARTICIPANT_VIEW ");
        query.append("where PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME ='EC' ) where IF_INDEX is not null and ");

        StringBuilder countQuery = new StringBuilder();
        countQuery.append("select count(*)  from (" );
        countQuery.append("select CUSTOMER_PORT_ID,IF_INDEX,SWITCH_NAME, ");
        countQuery.append("row_number() over (order by CUSTOMER_PORT_ID )r from IXP_PARTICIPANT_VIEW ");
        countQuery.append("where PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME ='EC' ) where IF_INDEX is not null");

        Map<String,Long> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>();
        BasicDataSource dataSource = (BasicDataSource)ac.getBean(TasConstants.DATA_SOURCE);

        int recordCount = 0;
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
             resultSet = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(countQuery.toString());
            resultSet.next();
            recordCount =  resultSet.getInt(1);
            int timeToExecute= recordCount>0?(recordCount/TasConstants.SNMP_EXDB_BATCH_SIZE)+1:0;

            for (int i = 0; i < timeToExecute ; i++) {
                StringBuilder prepareWhereClass = new StringBuilder();
                prepareWhereClass.append(" r >= ");
                prepareWhereClass.append(startCounter);
                prepareWhereClass.append(" and r <= ");
                prepareWhereClass.append(endCounter);
                Snmp5MinsDatabaseReadThread dbRead =  (Snmp5MinsDatabaseReadThread) ac.getBean(SNMP5MINSDATABASEREADTHREAD);

                ((Snmp5MinsDatabaseReadThread)dbRead).setMap(map);
                ((Snmp5MinsDatabaseReadThread)dbRead).setQuery(query.toString() + prepareWhereClass.toString());
                ((Snmp5MinsDatabaseReadThread)dbRead).setDataSource(dataSource);
                Runnable worker = dbRead;
                executor.execute(worker);
                startCounter = endCounter + 1;
                endCounter = endCounter + TasConstants.SNMP_EXDB_BATCH_SIZE;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
           throw new TasException(CLASS_NAME, TasConstants.METHOD_GETCACHE,e.getMessage(),e);
        } finally {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
                throw new TasException(CLASS_NAME, TasConstants.METHOD_GETCACHE,e.getMessage(),e);
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) { 
            logger.info("Waiting to process all the thread");
        }
        logger.info("SNMP 5 mins cache size "+map.size());
        return map;
    }
}



===========================================
package com.equinix.gse.apps.me.tas.app.ec.process.snmp.fivemins;

import com.equinix.gse.apps.me.tas.app.ec.dao.snmp.Snmp5MinsDatabaseReadThread;
import com.equinix.gse.apps.me.tas.core.TasException;
import com.equinix.gse.apps.me.tas.core.util.TasConstants;
import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

/**
 * User: vreddy
 */
@Service
public class Snmp5MinsCache {

    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Snmp5MinsCache.class);
    private static final String CLASS_NAME="Snmp5MinsCache";
    private static final String SNMP5MINSDATABASEREADTHREAD="snmp5MinsDatabaseReadThread";

    @Autowired
    private  ApplicationContext ac;

    public Map<String,Long> getCache() throws TasException{
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(TasConstants.THREAD_POOL_SIZE);
        int startCounter = 1;
        int endCounter = TasConstants.SNMP_EXDB_BATCH_SIZE;
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.append("select CUSTOMER_PORT_ID,IF_INDEX,SWITCH_NAME  from (" );
        query.append("select CUSTOMER_PORT_ID,IF_INDEX,SWITCH_NAME, ");
        query.append("row_number() over (order by CUSTOMER_PORT_ID )r from IXP_PARTICIPANT_VIEW ");
        query.append("where PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME ='EC' ) where IF_INDEX is not null and ");

        StringBuilder countQuery = new StringBuilder();
        countQuery.append("select count(*)  from (" );
        countQuery.append("select CUSTOMER_PORT_ID,IF_INDEX,SWITCH_NAME, ");
        countQuery.append("row_number() over (order by CUSTOMER_PORT_ID )r from IXP_PARTICIPANT_VIEW ");
        countQuery.append("where PRODUCT_SHORT_NAME ='EC' ) where IF_INDEX is not null");

        Map<String,Long> map = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Long>();
        BasicDataSource dataSource = (BasicDataSource)ac.getBean(TasConstants.DATA_SOURCE);

        int recordCount = 0;
        Connection conn = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        try {
            conn = dataSource.getConnection();
             resultSet = conn.createStatement().executeQuery(countQuery.toString());
            resultSet.next();
            recordCount =  resultSet.getInt(1);
            int timeToExecute= recordCount>0?(recordCount/TasConstants.SNMP_EXDB_BATCH_SIZE)+1:0;

            for (int i = 0; i < timeToExecute ; i++) {
                StringBuilder prepareWhereClass = new StringBuilder();
                prepareWhereClass.append(" r >= ");
                prepareWhereClass.append(startCounter);
                prepareWhereClass.append(" and r <= ");
                prepareWhereClass.append(endCounter);
                Snmp5MinsDatabaseReadThread dbRead =  (Snmp5MinsDatabaseReadThread) ac.getBean(SNMP5MINSDATABASEREADTHREAD);

                ((Snmp5MinsDatabaseReadThread)dbRead).setMap(map);
                ((Snmp5MinsDatabaseReadThread)dbRead).setQuery(query.toString() + prepareWhereClass.toString());
                ((Snmp5MinsDatabaseReadThread)dbRead).setDataSource(dataSource);
                Runnable worker = dbRead;
                executor.execute(worker);
                startCounter = endCounter + 1;
                endCounter = endCounter + TasConstants.SNMP_EXDB_BATCH_SIZE;
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
           throw new TasException(CLASS_NAME, TasConstants.METHOD_GETCACHE,e.getMessage(),e);
        } finally {
            try {
                resultSet.close();
                conn.close();
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                logger.error(e.getMessage(),e);
                throw new TasException(CLASS_NAME, TasConstants.METHOD_GETCACHE,e.getMessage(),e);
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) { 
            logger.info("Waiting to process all the thread");
        }
        logger.info("SNMP 5 mins cache size "+map.size());
        return map;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;

public class MailProcessor implements Runnable {

    String downloadDirectory = "C:/tmp/downloads/";

    private Message message;

    public MailProcessor() {

    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Starting processing a message with thread id"
                + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        try {
            readMails();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Finished processing a message with thread id"
                + Thread.currentThread().getId());

    }

    public void readMails() throws MessagingException {

        Address[] from = message.getFrom();
        System.out.println("-------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Date : " + message.getSentDate());
        System.out.println("From : " + from[0]);
        System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
        System.out.println("Content :");
        processMessageBody(message);
        System.out.println("--------------------------------");

    }

    public void processMessageBody(Message message) {
        try {
            Object content = message.getContent();
            // check for string
            // then check for multipart
            if (content instanceof String) {
                System.out.println(content);
            } else if (content instanceof Multipart) {
                Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) content;
                procesMultiPart(multiPart);
            } else if (content instanceof InputStream) {
                InputStream inStream = (InputStream) content;
                int ch;
                while ((ch = inStream.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.write(ch);
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void procesMultiPart(Multipart content) {
        InputStream inStream = null;
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < content.getCount(); i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = content.getBodyPart(i);
                Object o;

                o = bodyPart.getContent();
                if (o instanceof String) {
                    System.out.println("Text = " + o);
                } else if (null != bodyPart.getDisposition()
                        && bodyPart.getDisposition().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                Part.ATTACHMENT)) {
                    String fileName = bodyPart.getFileName();
                    System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);
                    inStream = bodyPart.getInputStream();
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(downloadDirectory
                            + fileName));
                    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[4096];// KB
                    int numRead = 0;
                    while ((numRead = inStream.read(tempBuffer)) != -1) {
                        outStream.write(tempBuffer);
                    }

                }
                // else?

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inStream != null) {
                try {
                    inStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (outStream != null) {

                try {
                    outStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public MailProcessor setMessage(Message message) {
        this.message = message;
        return this;
    }
}

===========================================================================


import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.mail.Message;

public class MailServer {

    public static void start(int threadCount,
            int frequencyInSecondsToListenMail) {

        long lastFinished = System.currentTimeMillis();
        do {
            if ((System.currentTimeMillis() - lastFinished) / 1000 >= frequencyInSecondsToListenMail) {
                readMails(threadCount);
            }
        } while (true);
    }

    private static void readMails(int threadCount) {
        List<Message> recentMessages = MailUtility.readMessages();
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors
                .newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
        if(recentMessages == null || recentMessages.isEmpty()){
            System.out.println("No messages found.");
        }
        for (Message message : recentMessages) {
            executorService
                    .execute(new MailProcessor().setMessage(message));
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MailServer.start(2, 2);
    }
}
=======================================================================


import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Flags.Flag;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;


public final class MailUtility {

    public static List<Message> readMessages() {

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.host", "imap.gmail.com");
        properties.setProperty("mail.port", "");
        properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "imaps");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    final Properties mailServerProperties = PropertyFileReader
                            .getProperties("mail-server.properties");
                    String username = mailServerProperties
                            .getProperty("username");
                    String password = mailServerProperties
                            .getProperty("password");

                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        Store store;
        try {
            store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect();
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(
                    new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));
            List<Message> result = new ArrayList<Message>();
            for(Message message : messages){
                result.add(new MimeMessage((MimeMessage)message));
            }
            inbox.close(false);
            store.close();
            return result;
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }
}
==========================================================================

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.Flags.Flag;

public class MessagesProcessor implements Runnable {

    String downloadDirectory = "C:/tmp/downloads/";

    private List<Message> messages;

    public MessagesProcessor() {

    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Starting processing " + messages.size()
                + " messages in the thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        try {
            readMails();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Finished processing " + messages.size()
                + " messages in the thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

    }

    public void readMails() throws MessagingException {

        for (Message message : messages) {
            Address[] from = message.getFrom();
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Date : " + message.getSentDate());
            System.out.println("From : " + from[0]);
            System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
            System.out.println("Content :");
            processMessageBody(message);
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");
            message.setFlag(Flag.SEEN, true);
        }

    }

    public void processMessageBody(Message message) {
        try {
            Object content = message.getContent();
            // check for string
            // then check for multipart
            if (content instanceof String) {
                System.out.println(content);
            } else if (content instanceof Multipart) {
                Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) content;
                procesMultiPart(multiPart);
            } else if (content instanceof InputStream) {
                InputStream inStream = (InputStream) content;
                int ch;
                while ((ch = inStream.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.write(ch);
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void procesMultiPart(Multipart content) {
        InputStream inStream = null;
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < content.getCount(); i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = content.getBodyPart(i);
                Object o;

                o = bodyPart.getContent();
                if (o instanceof String) {
                    System.out.println("Text = " + o);
                } else if (null != bodyPart.getDisposition()
                        && bodyPart.getDisposition().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                Part.ATTACHMENT)) {
                    String fileName = bodyPart.getFileName();
                    System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);
                    inStream = bodyPart.getInputStream();
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(downloadDirectory
                            + fileName));
                    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[4096];// KB
                    int numRead;
                    while ((numRead = inStream.read(tempBuffer)) != -1) {
                        outStream.write(tempBuffer);
                    }

                }
                // else?

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inStream != null) {
                try {
                    inStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (outStream != null) {

                try {
                    outStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public MessagesProcessor setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
        return this;
    }
}
============================================================================


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public final class PropertyFileReader {

    public static Properties getProperties(String filename) {
        ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader();
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try {
            properties.load(contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(filename));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you change. Don't just past a solution. Tell what you have done and basically what to change. This would be more useful.

Answer (score 0):

```
  for(int i=0; i < timeToExecute; i++){
            for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                Runnable runner = null;
                if(i+1 == timeToExecute){
                    endIndex = count;
                    runner = new TaskPrint(startIndex, endIndex, inbox);
                } else {
                    runner = new TaskPrint(startIndex, endIndex, inbox);
                }
                executor.execute(runner);
                startIndex = endIndex + 1;
                endIndex = endIndex + 200;
                i++;                
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DAOUtils {

    public static void createTable(){
        String createSql = "CREATE TABLE MAILBOX " +
                " from VARCHAR(255), " + 
                " sentDate VARCHAR(255), " + 
                " subject VARCHAR(255), " + 
                " message VARCHAR(255)"; 

        Connection con = DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection();
        Statement stmt;
        try {
            stmt = con.createStatement();
            stmt.executeUpdate(createSql);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
    }

    public static void insertRow(MailInfo mes){
        Connection conn = DBConnection.getInstance().getConnection();

        String sql = "INSERT INTO MAILBOX (from, sentDate, subject, message)" +
                "VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)";
        try {
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            preparedStatement.setString(1, mes.getFrom());
            preparedStatement.setString(2, mes.getSentDate());
            preparedStatement.setString(3, mes.getSubject());
            preparedStatement.setString(4, mes.getMessageContent());
            preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
        } catch (SQLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}

===========================================================================

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.Properties;


public class DBConnection {

    private static Connection connect;
    private static DBConnection instance;

    private DBConnection()
    {     
        final Properties mailServerProperties = PropertyFileReader
                .getProperties("mail-server.properties");
        String username = mailServerProperties
                .getProperty("db_username");
        String password = mailServerProperties
                .getProperty("db_password");
        String ip = mailServerProperties
                .getProperty("ip");

        try {        
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://" +ip +"/database",username,password);
        }catch(SQLException e)
        {
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }catch(ClassNotFoundException e)
        {    
            System.err.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }

      public static DBConnection getInstance()
      {
          if(instance == null) {
              instance = new DBConnection();
          }
          return instance;
      }

      public static Connection getConnection(){
          return connect;
      }

}

=========================================================================


public class MailInfo {

    private String sentDate;
    private String subject;
    private String from;
    private String messageContent;

    public String getSentDate() {
        return sentDate;
    }
    public void setSentDate(String sentDate) {
        this.sentDate = sentDate;
    }
    public String getSubject() {
        return subject;
    }
    public void setSubject(String subject) {
        this.subject = subject;
    }
    public String getFrom() {
        return from;
    }
    public void setFrom(String from) {
        this.from = from;
    }
    public String getMessageContent() {
        return messageContent;
    }
    public void setMessageContent(String messageContent) {
        this.messageContent = messageContent;
    }

}

===========================================================================
mail-server.properties

username = hhh60
password = $test123$

db_username = root
db_password = root

ip = localhost:3305

use_db = false
==========================================================================


import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javax.mail.Message;

public class MailServer {

    public static void start(int messageCountForEachThread, int threadCount) {
        List<Message> messages = MailUtility.readMessages();
        int messageLength = messages.size();
        if (messages == null || messages.size() == 0) {
            System.out.println("No messages found");
            return;
        }
        System.out.println("Number of messages found " + messageLength);
        if (messageLength <= messageCountForEachThread) {
            new Thread(new MessagesProcessor().setMessages(messages)).start();
        } else {
            ExecutorService executorService = Executors
                    .newFixedThreadPool(threadCount);
            int x = messageLength / messageCountForEachThread;
            int remaining = messageLength % messageCountForEachThread;
            int i = 1;
            while (i <= x) {

                int startIndex = (i - 1) * messageCountForEachThread;
                int endIndex = startIndex + messageCountForEachThread;

                List<Message> messagesForEachThread = messages.subList(
                        startIndex, endIndex);

                executorService.execute(new MessagesProcessor()
                        .setMessages(messagesForEachThread));
                i++;
            }
            int startIndex = i - 1 * messageCountForEachThread;
            int endIndex = startIndex + remaining;
            List<Message> messagesForEachThread = messages.subList(startIndex,
                    endIndex);

            executorService.execute(new MessagesProcessor()
                    .setMessages(messagesForEachThread));

            executorService.shutdown();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MailServer.start(2, 2);
    }
}
=======================================================================

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Flags;
import javax.mail.Flags.Flag;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;
import javax.mail.search.FlagTerm;



public final class MailUtility {

    public static List<Message> readMessages() {

        final Properties mailServerProperties = PropertyFileReader
                .getProperties("mail-server.properties");
        boolean useDb = Boolean.parseBoolean(mailServerProperties.getProperty("use_db"));

        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("mail.host", "imap.gmail.com");
        properties.setProperty("mail.port", "");
        properties.setProperty("mail.transport.protocol", "imaps");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(properties,
                new javax.mail.Authenticator() {
                    String username = mailServerProperties
                            .getProperty("username");
                    String password = mailServerProperties
                            .getProperty("password");

                    protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                        return new PasswordAuthentication(username, password);
                    }
                });

        Store store;
        try {
            store = session.getStore("imaps");
            store.connect();
            Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
            inbox.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);
            Message messages[] = inbox.search(new FlagTerm(
                    new Flags(Flag.SEEN), false));

            if(useDb){
                DAOUtils.createTable();
            }

            return Arrays.asList(messages);
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}

================================================================


import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;

public class MessagesProcessor implements Runnable {

    String downloadDirectory = "C:/tmp/downloads/";
    boolean useDb;

    private List<Message> messages;

    public MessagesProcessor() {
        final Properties mailServerProperties = PropertyFileReader
                .getProperties("mail-server.properties");
        useDb = Boolean.parseBoolean(mailServerProperties.getProperty("use_db"));
    }

    public void run() {

        System.out.println("Starting processing " + messages.size()
                + " messages in the thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        try {
            readMails();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Finished processing " + messages.size()
                + " messages in the thread " + Thread.currentThread().getId());

    }

    public void readMails() throws MessagingException {

        for (Message message : messages) {
            Address[] from = message.getFrom();
            System.out.println("-------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Date : " + message.getSentDate());
            System.out.println("From : " + from[0]);
            System.out.println("Subject: " + message.getSubject());
            System.out.println("Content :");
            processMessageBody(message);
            System.out.println("--------------------------------");

            if(useDb){
                MailInfo info = new MailInfo();
                info.setFrom(from[0].toString());
                info.setSentDate(message.getSentDate().toString());
                info.setSubject(message.getSubject());
                info.setMessageContent(message.toString());
                DAOUtils.insertRow(info);
            }

        }

    }

    public void processMessageBody(Message message) {
        try {
            Object content = message.getContent();
            // check for string
            // then check for multipart
            if (content instanceof String) {
                System.out.println(content);
            } else if (content instanceof Multipart) {
                Multipart multiPart = (Multipart) content;
                procesMultiPart(multiPart);
            } else if (content instanceof InputStream) {
                InputStream inStream = (InputStream) content;
                int ch;
                while ((ch = inStream.read()) != -1) {
                    System.out.write(ch);
                }

            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void procesMultiPart(Multipart content) {
        InputStream inStream = null;
        FileOutputStream outStream = null;
        try {

            for (int i = 0; i < content.getCount(); i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = content.getBodyPart(i);
                Object o;

                o = bodyPart.getContent();
                if (o instanceof String) {
                    System.out.println("Text = " + o);
                } else if (null != bodyPart.getDisposition()
                        && bodyPart.getDisposition().equalsIgnoreCase(
                                Part.ATTACHMENT)) {
                    String fileName = bodyPart.getFileName();
                    System.out.println("fileName = " + fileName);
                    inStream = bodyPart.getInputStream();
                    File f = new File(downloadDirectory + fileName);
                    if(!f.exists()){
                    System.out.println("Downloading file : " + fileName + " .............");
                    outStream = new FileOutputStream(f);                    
                    byte[] tempBuffer = new byte[4096];// KB
                    int numRead = 0;
                    while ((numRead = inStream.read(tempBuffer)) != -1) {
                        outStream.write(tempBuffer);
                        }
                    System.out.println("Download completed");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Given file name already exists");
                    }
                }

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MessagingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (inStream != null) {
                try {
                    inStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            if (outStream != null) {

                try {
                    outStream.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }

    public MessagesProcessor setMessages(List<Message> messages) {
        this.messages = messages;
        return this;
    }
}

==================================================================


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Properties;

public final class PropertyFileReader {

    public static Properties getProperties(String filename) {
        ClassLoader contextClassLoader = Thread.currentThread()
                .getContextClassLoader();
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        try {
            properties.load(contextClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(filename));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return properties;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package Test.TestArtifact;

import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.mail.Address;
import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;

public class TaskPrint implements Runnable{

    private Message messages;
    private Date startDate;

    public TaskPrint(Date startDate, Message messages){
        this.startDate = startDate;
        this.messages = messages;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            if(messages.getSentDate().after(startDate) && messages.getSentDate().before(startDate)){
                Address[] in = messages.getFrom();
                String contentType = messages.getContentType();
                String messageContent = "";
                String attachFiles = "";
                if(contentType.contains("multiport")){
                    Multipart multipart = (Multipart) messages.getContent();
                    int noOfParts = multipart.getCount();
                    for(int partCount =0; partCount < noOfParts; partCount++){
                        MimeBodyPart mime = (MimeBodyPart) multipart.getBodyPart(partCount);
                        if(Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(mime.getDisposition())){
                            String fileName = mime.getFileName();
                            attachFiles += fileName + ",";
                            if(fileName.endsWith("=")){
                                mime.saveFile("C:\\tmp\\downloads" + fileName);
                            } else {
                                messageContent = mime.getContent().toString();
                            }
                        }
                        if(attachFiles.length() > 1){
                            attachFiles = attachFiles.substring(0, attachFiles.length() - 2);
                        } else if(contentType.contains("text/plain") || contentType.contains("text/html")) {
                            Object content = messages.getContent();
                            if(content != null){
                                messageContent = content.toString();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package Test.TestArtifact;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;


public class ExecutorServiceExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
        ExecutorServiceExample eService = new ExecutorServiceExample();
        Folder inbox = eService.getInboxFolder();
        int count = eService.getMailCount();
        Message messages = inbox.getMessage(count);
        System.out.println("Total Mail count = " + count);

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        int waitTime = 1000000;

        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

        Date startDate;
        Date endDate;
        try {
            startDate = formatter.parse("2015-10-01");
            endDate = formatter.parse("2015-10-31");
            while(startDate.before(endDate)){
                for(int j=0;j<5;j++){
                    Runnable runner = new TaskPrint(startDate,messages);
                    executor.execute(runner);
                }
            }
        } catch (ParseException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }


        try {
            Thread.sleep(waitTime);
            executor.shutdown();
            executor.awaitTermination(waitTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        System.exit(0);
    }

    private Folder getInboxFolder() throws MessagingException{
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imap");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props);
        Store store = session.getStore("imap");
        store.connect("", "", "");
        store.getFolder("INBOX").open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        return inbox;       
    }

    private int getMailCount() throws MessagingException{
        int count = getInboxFolder().getMessageCount();
        return count;

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;

import javax.mail.Folder;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Store;


public class ExecutorServiceExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MessagingException {
        ExecutorServiceExample eService = new ExecutorServiceExample();
        Folder inbox = eService.getInboxFolder();
        Message[] messages = inbox.getMessages();
        System.out.println("Total Mail count = " + messages.length);

        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

        for(Message message: messages){
            Runnable runner = new TaskPrint(message);
            executor.execute(runner);
        }
        System.out.println("Maximum threads inside pool " + executor.getMaximumPoolSize());
        executor.shutdown();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            executor.shutdown();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private Folder getInboxFolder() throws MessagingException{
        Properties props = System.getProperties();
        props.setProperty("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
        Session session = Session.getInstance(props,null);
        Store store = session.getStore();
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "aaa@gmail.com", "aaaaa");
        Folder inbox = store.getFolder("INBOX");
        inbox.open(Folder.READ_ONLY);
        return inbox;       
    }
}
```

Comment: It is good that you posted the code for an answer but it would benefit if you explained the solution as well.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.Part;

public class TaskPrint implements Runnable{

    private Message message;

    public TaskPrint(Message message){
        this.message = message;
    }
    public void run() {
        try {
            Multipart multipart = (Multipart) message.getContent();
            for (int i = 0; i < multipart.getCount(); i++) {
                BodyPart bodyPart = multipart.getBodyPart(i);
                if(!Part.ATTACHMENT.equalsIgnoreCase(bodyPart.getDisposition()) &&
                        bodyPart.getFileName() != null) {
                     continue; // dealing with attachments only
                 } 
                System.out.println("Message subject " + message.getSubject());
                 InputStream is = bodyPart.getInputStream();
                 File f = new File("c:/tmp/" + bodyPart.getFileName());
                 FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(f);
                 byte[] buf = new byte[4096];
                 int bytesRead;
                 while((bytesRead = is.read(buf))!=-1) {
                     fos.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                 }
                 fos.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(MessagingException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Move code inside to this loop.          if((message.getContent() instanceof Multipart)){}